# Stdout without LineWriter

Tags: rust

Why `std::io::stdout()` returns stdout with `LineWriter`?

How can we get `stdout` without `LineWriter`?

https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6hoayo/how_do_i_write_to_stdout_without_line_buffering/

```
    use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;
    let stdout = unsafe { std::fs::File::from_raw_fd(1) };
    let mut writer = std::io::BufWriter::with_capacity(2, stdout);
    writer.write(b"S").unwrap();
```

there is a sulotion here with unsafe code but why there isn't any simple way to do that?

Comment: A lot of *why* questions tend to not be good questions because they invite speculation if there's no clearly documented rationale. The closest source I found is from discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58326). There's a bit of back-and-forth with doubts about the benefits and performance and plenty of questions about behavior in various cases.

Comment: My own two cents is that the current Stdout implementation gives a lot of good guarantees for behaving as people expect (both for flushing behavior and multi-threaded behavior). If you find yourself hindered by the line-buffering you can use OS-specific features to tune it how you want, as in one implementation provided.

Comment: Because currently the rust developers have decided not to try and infer which buffering policy *should* be used based on external information (e.g. the type of stdout), or to provide configurable streams (`setvbuf`). As @kmdreko's link shows, this is a known deficiency.